# Lightning Community: Load with browser/local language

Tags: lightning-community, language, default-value, browser, languagelocalekey

What I want to achieve is loading my community page with the current browser or local selected language.

So far I have different page variations for each language, so I want to load the language corresponding to the browser/local language or (if there is not translated language for the current browser language) load a default language. All this **without having to redirect** the user once the page has already load with the default language.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have used custom labels while using sites. To determine the browser language you can use Accept-Language.

```
language = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Accept-Language').substring(0,2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think that does not work for Lighning Communities, do you know a way to do it with Communitites?